# Can I re-use the same SVG in a page and apply different CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG file that I want to use in a web page. I want the image to appear multiple times, but to apply different CSS styles to each one.

**Is this possible?**

### Clarification

When I say "apply different CSS styles", I mean that I want to style the SVG contents (stroke, color, radius, etc), not just the width of an `<img>` or something.

Also, I don't consider "copy and paste the SVG contents" to be "re-using" it. I want to create a file like `logo.svg` and reference it from the HTML.

Comment: You bet..see [**this article on CSS-Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No, not currently

Styling the contents (stroke, fill, etc) of an SVG from a containing HTML document is currently not supported.

@RobertLongson was kind enough to point me to the [SVG Parameters spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/), which could provide a partial solution. It is not implemented in any browser, but can be used with a Javascript shim. However, when I emailed the SVG working group with a question about it, I was told:

> The SVG Parameters doc is currently out-of-date.  The plan at the
>   moment is to integrate it with CSS Custom Properties and var(); the
>   spec will then become an alternative way to define a custom property.

And

> SVG <img>s are actually in a separate document entirely; it's
>   basically the same as an <iframe>, just locked down more strictly.  We
>   don't allow direct selection across document boundaries for a
>   combination of security, sanity, and performance reasons.
>
> That said, it seems reasonable for the Parameters spec to define a way
>   to take values from the referencing environment, so you'd set the
>   property on the <img> itself and it would transfer through to the
>   contained document *at the document's request*.

### A non-spec-compliant hack: the `use` tag

For the record, the following seemed to accomplish my stated goals (technique borrowed from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/)), but @RobertLongson let me know that it only worked in Firefox (I think I was using version 31) because Firefox was not compliant with the spec.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SVG Reuse Demo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
    <style type="text/css">
      .circle   .uno { stroke: orange; stroke-width: 5px; }
      .circle-1 .uno { fill: blue; }
      .circle-2 .uno { fill: red; }
      .circle-3 .uno { fill: green; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Single definition of SVG -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
      <symbol id="disc" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle class="uno" cx="50" cy="50" r="40">
      </symbol>
    </svg>
    <!-- Re-use; each is styled differently (see above) -->
    <svg class="circle circle-1">
      <use xlink:href="#disc">
    </svg>
    <svg class="circle circle-2">
      <use xlink:href="#disc">
    </svg>
    <svg class="circle circle-3">
      <use xlink:href="#disc">
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Even if it were standard, this technique would be less than ideal; the ideal solution would allow using an SVG defined **in an external file**, like `circles.svg`.

This is because:

1. It is clutter to paste it into the HTML (my actual use case may be 300 lines of SVG)
2. If it were a separate file, I could re-use it in other HTML documents
3. I could edit it with SVG-specific syntax highlighting
4. It could be requested and cached separately from the HTML document
5. ... basically all the other reasons we normally put CSS and images in separate files instead of inline in HTML. :)

Comment: Are you doing this on Firefox? If so the reason it works is that Firefox's use doesn't work per the SVG specification. You can't really do this with `<use>` and once we get round to fixing it it won't work like that. Try viewing it in Opera 12 to see what it should look like.

Comment: @RobertLongson - yep, this was on Firefox 31.0 on OSX Mavericks. Is there any spec-compatible way to accomplish this?

Comment: No. There's this, no UA has natively implemented it but it has a javascript shim: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/

Comment: Wow. Thanks for bringing genuine expertise to my question. :) Followup: any link to the shim? Any reason why I couldn't use this (with the shim) to pass in a URL for an external stylesheet? And is it silly to use the shim if a native implementation isn't forthcoming?

Comment: try one of the examples, they all use the shim. The document is still in progress.

Comment: verified in IE11. looks amazing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it can be easily done using SVG injection, and it should work on all Browsers that support SVG.

With [SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject) your HTML may look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="svg-inject.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .redImage {
      /* Your CSS for the red image here */
    }

    .greenImage {
      /* Your CSS for the green image here */
    }
  <style>
</head>
<body>
  <img class="redImage" src="image.svg" onload="SVGInject(this)" />
  <img class="greenImage" src="image.svg" onload="SVGInject(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```

The `onload="SVGInject(this)"` triggers the injection after the SVG is loaded and replaces the `<img>` element with the SVG markup from the specified SVG file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely!

If each occurrence is unique, simply apply an `id` attribute to the `svg` then reference it and its children with the id prefixing any selectors, e.g

`<svg id='myimage ... />`

Then in your css:

`#myimage line{...}`

Would for example apply styles to the `line` elements within the `myimage` svg.

I'd also recommend having a look at the [**MDN article on CSS selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: They don't need an `id` as such and each occurrence is already unique as they are a new instance. svg tags are just tags so they can be styled like any other tags and any CSS selector uses to customize them would work.

Comment: @gillesc In terms of CSS and HTML (and the context of the question), an `id` is a unique identifier - you can use nth-child, a class etc- however its likely best using id for its purpose as a 1-on-1 identifier.

Comment: Yes, well, it all depends on your CSS structure really, a bunch of classes may be better, `nth-child` is of course a nightmare to maintain even if it would work. Just wanted to clarify in case it may not be obvious to all :)

Comment: source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors `[..]CSS gives priority to the rule that has the more specific selector. An ID selector is more specific than a class selector, which in turn is more specific than a tag selector.` To link specific styles to a specific element and no other, and to protect against unforseen clashing, `id` is most appropriate. If you want to target a specific element with specific CSS, `id` is the recommendation over a collection of classes, which is more suited to a collection of elements and/or shared CSS rules.

Comment: But true- it does all depend on context :)

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm trying to use the *same* image repeatedly. I don't want to paste the exact same text into multiple `<svg>` tags. It looks like maybe the `use` keyword shown here is the trick? http://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/

Comment: @SW4 in your example, did you intend to do `<svg src="somefile.svg">`, or to actually define the SVG inline in the tag? Using `src`, I have not been able to style the elements inside that SVG. Doing it inline is something I'd like to avoid; see my answer below.

Answer (score -2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4jswL/)**

html

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174" xml:space="preserve" class="logo">
    <path class="kiwi" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
  c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
  c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933
  c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991
  c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875
  c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489
  c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309
  c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876
  c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413
  c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566
  c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156
  c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351
  c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247
  c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331
  z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111
  C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z" />
</svg>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174" xml:space="preserve" class="logo">
    <path class="kiwi" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
  c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
  c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933
  c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991
  c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875
  c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489
  c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309
  c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876
  c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413
  c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566
  c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156
  c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351
  c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247
  c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331
  z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111
  C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z" />
</svg>
```

css

```
#Layer_1 {
  width: 200px;
}
#Layer_2 {
  width: 100px;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

---

You can use it this way if you don't want to use the whole values of `svg` multiple times.

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/hpvEe)**

html

```
<img class="papa" src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">   
<img class="mama"  src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">   
<img class="baby"  src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">
```

css

```
.papa {
  width: 250px;
}

.mama {
  width: 100px; 
}

.baby {
  width: 50px; 
}
```

source : http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: `svg` example would have been better for a `svg` question

Comment: Yeah didn't need it, just realized my eyes were obviously not working right and should have read till the end of each lines! :)

Comment: So the way you're re-using the same SVG is to paste it multiple times into the page?

Comment: I made an edit, what you can do is save the svg file and use it multiple times.